# Copy to Clipboard element's text value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

Edit: I do not try to copy textarea or input value so it is not a duplicate question as suggested.

Can I use copy to clipboard for an element's text value?

Such as I want to copy terra1

```
<span id="terra-wallet-address">terra1</span>
```

And jQuery:

```
  jQuery('#terra-wallet-address').focus();
  jQuery('#terra-wallet-address').select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  jQuery('.copied').text("Copied to clipboard").show().fadeOut(1200);
```

I also tried .val() and .text() but did not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I am not using any input or textarea. So, no unfortunately it does not answer my question.

Comment: If you don't have an input (or content-editable-div) then what do you think `.focus()` is doing?   You can only copy from an `input` (or similar), not from a `span`

Comment: Hi Ataman, How much I understood your question you want to copy text inside the <span> element that's it?

Comment: The linked question provides you a way to generate a `textarea`, add the value you want to copy into that textarea and then copy to clipboard from the (hidden) textarea.  There are other answers that have a similar process.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create a temporary textarea, you can programmatically select the text inside the element (with [`Document.createRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange) and [`Range.selectNodeContents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNodeContents)), then call `execCommand`.

Note that you'll need to call `execCommand` inside an event handler.

```js
var r = document.createRange();
var w = document.getElementById("terra-wallet-address");
r.selectNodeContents(w);
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(r);
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.execCommand('copy');
  jQuery('.copied').text("Copied to clipboard").show().fadeOut(1200);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="terra-wallet-address">terra1</span>

<button id="btn">copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't `focus()` an element, but you can use other methods, like [`create range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange), and then execute the copy command.

I also made a tiny library that lets you copy inputs, textareas, divs, and any other elements: https://github.com/codingjlu/copyjs